# I Have an array of the Objects Inside Which i have key which is again Array of Objects Now I need to Check the Condition where id = 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach-loop-container

I have to check  condition `id` = `4` where I need to delete that complete object..from (`description` to budgetOf) as per the below code need to display the  1 object only:

```
[{
  description: 'values123',
  noOfdays: null,
  values: [{
      id: 1,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isValidEmail: 'false',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    }
  ],
  budgetOf: null,
}, {
  description: 'values643',
  noOfdays: null,
  values: [{
      id: 6,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      isValidEmail: 'false',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    }
  ],
  budgetOf: null,
}, {
  description: 'values143',
  noOfdays: null,
  values: [{
      id: 1,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      isValidEmail: 'false',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isValidEmail: 'true',
    }
  ],
  budgetOf: null,
}]
```

Comment: **i have to check  condition id = 4 where i need to delete that complete object..from (description to budgetOf) as per the below code need to display the  1 object only**

Answer (score 0):

Can be resolved using above code, hope this helps.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < reqArray.length; i++) {
    const { values } = reqArray[i];
    for (let k = 0; k < values.length; k++) { 
      if (values[k].id === 4) { 
        delete reqArray[i]; 
      }
    }
  }
```